# Is there any functional difference between direct sub array copy into 2-D array and using for loop in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have written 2-pieces of code to copy sub-array elements of a 2-D array as below

First Method:

```
 String [][] actual = new String[5][5];
 String [] arrayToCopy = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
 actual[0] = arrayToCopy;
```

Second Method:

```
String [][] actual = new String[5][5];
String [] arrayToCopy = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    actual[0][i] = arrayToCopy[i];
```

Is there any difference in functionality between above two methods as they are generating same output when I print the 2-D array?

Comment: There is no need for 2D array to ask this kind of question. Tip: array is an Object.

Answer (score 2):

One difference that you will need to worry about is that when you say

```
actual[0] = arrayToCopy;
```

You are actually not "copying" your array. Instead, you are replacing `actual[0]` 
 with a reference to `arrayToCopy`. If you change the array from either variable, the change will be reflected in the other. You can see it yourself:

```
System.out.println(actual[0][0]);   // prints "1"
arrayToCopy[0] = "5";
System.out.println(actual[0][0]);   // prints "5"
```

In the second approach, `actual[0]` and `arrayToCopy` reference different arrays, and you are actually "copying" elements from one array to the other. Changing one, will not change the other.

As for your question, does it differ in "functionality"? Depends on what you mean, but if the data is read-only then it's not that big of a deal. It only becomes a problem when you can modify the data and you're not careful and start changing things that shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, assignments are by reference (except in primitive types (boolean, int, float, double, short, char, byte, long).  When you do something like your first attempt, you don't copy the array, you are just referencing it in another variable.

```
 actual[0] = arrayToCopy;
```

If you try doing something like that:

```
 actual[0][3] = 5;

 System.out.println(arrayToCopy[3]);
```

You will find 5.  Any change happens to one, is reflected on the others.

But your second attempts copies the array.

If you want performant copying, consider using `System.arrayCopy` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)

If you want performant programming and your array isn't shared between different objects, you could use the referencing solution (your first one).
But if you want to be in the safe side, or you worry about threading and data sharing between different objects, try copying.